# AES implementations

Tags: actionscript-3, encryption

What is the fastest method for decrypting data using AES in AS3? Someone told me that there are faster ways to decrypt data than the as3crypto implementation.
How many ways are there to encrypt/decrypt data using aes?

I managed to speed up the as3crypto aes implementation with about 40%, yet he says that aes should be faster.

I'm using aes to decrypt a stream to play music.

Comment: Maybe you could consider [AS3 Crypto Wrapper](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/alchemy/libraries/as3crypto.zip) (written with Alchemy).